# HTTP (REST) requests through Python

Tags: python, rest, http, python-requests

I am trying to consume a rest API through Python.

The requests are the same as here:
https://github.com/jvalue/open-data-service/blob/main/doc/example-requests/adapter.http

I tested nearly all possible encodings and JSON serializations possible.
I also played with the headers, but in vain.
I tested with Requests, and also urllib.
No matter what, it always returns 400 or 415.

But, it works well outside Python.
For example, using VScode Rest client extension mentioned here:
https://github.com/jvalue/open-data-service/tree/main/doc/example-requests

The code is somewhat OOP, so I can't copy and paste a whole module. But, I have tried to write an excerpt that shows the same pattern.

I tried this:

```
j ={'type': 'HTTP', 'parameters': {'location': 'https://www.bka.de/SharedDocs/Downloads/DE/Publikationen/PolizeilicheKriminalstatistik/2018/BKATabellen/FaelleLaenderKreiseStaedte/BKA-LKS-F-03-T01-Kreise_csv.csv?__blob=publicationFile&v=3','encoding': 'UTF-8'}}

resp = requests.post(url, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'},json=json.dumps(j))
```

and this:

```
resp = requests.post(url, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'},json=json.dumps(j).encode("UTF-8"))
```

and this:

```
resp = requests.post(url, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'},json=j)
```

and this:

```
resp = requests.post(url, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'},data=json.dumps(j))
```

and this:

```
resp = requests.post(url, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'},params=json.dumps(j))
```

and more different combinations, but all threw 400 eventually no matter what.

Also tried loading the json from a file:

```
with open('req.json','rb') as payload:
  return requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload.read())
```

Comment: Try adding some of your Python code, so we can try and help figure out what went wrong.

Comment: What’s the URL?

Comment: You show POST requests, is authentication needed?

Comment: @barny The service runs locally, the url is localhost something.http://localhost:9000/api/adapter/preview. No, there is no authentication needed.

Comment: There has to be an objective reason why you get different response from your Python code. The way to examine the http protocol conversations is to use a mitm proxy like Telerik Fiddler Classic (Windows) or mitm (Linux). Record what your vscode does then compare with what your Python code does. As no-one but you has your REST API it’s _you_ who will have to work out what’s going wrong. It’s probably be a difference in headers.

Comment: did that right now, but with no difference. But I noticed the content length is different (279 in vscode rest extension vs. 271 in Python bytes string -UTF-8 encoded-). Even though I use json.dumps with indent=2 and separators that makes it in the same format visually.

Comment: There’s no magic wand involved: the server can only respond to what it receives in the request: the URL, the parameters, the headers, the body. If the response is different then what the server receives must be different in some way that affects the server.

Comment: @barny That's why I am asking. There is some subtle reason that is not visible even after literally tens of trials. I am currently still testing more ways, and I think the problem lies in Python requests json serialization. Will give it  a thorough look maybe I could know what causes the issue.

Comment: But you’ve only shown the Python side of the story, and then not the full encoded HTTP POST, so I’m not sure how you expect to get ny help.

Comment: @Barny If you know you Python Requests you would automatically understand that the body is basically a bytes string of whatever j is -after JSON serialization-.